# Restrictions on a rational expression with two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm studying High School Algebra and it had this question:

> Simplify: $\frac{2x^2-12xy+18y^2}{3x^2-27y^2}$

If I solve this so that it wouldn't be undefined, would I have to put restrictions for x, or y, or both?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\frac{2(x^2-6xy+9y^2)}{3(x^2-9y^2)}$$ and think about the binomial formula.

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to simplify the common factors, but to keep the same function, you must exclude from the domain the conditions that caused the expression to be indeterminate (namely, $x\ne3y$).

Comment: What about if y = x/3?

Comment: @Joe The denominator will become zero and the fraction will be undefined.

Comment: @Joe: don't you understand my answer ?

Comment: So that means the answer to this question has 4 restrictions?

Comment: @YvesDaoust So that means the answer to this question has 4 restrictions?

Comment: @joe: which four ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust x = 3y, x = -3y, y = x/3, and y = -x/3

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, isn't the denominator 3(x + 3y)(x - 3y)? Wouldn't those values make the expression undefined?

Comment: @joe: why $x=3y$ and $x/3=y$ ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust Because it makes the fraction undefined.

Comment: @Joe: I am afraid you don't see what is wrong with that.

Comment: I'm asking if these four values make the expression undefined and if it does, does that mean I have to specify that those four values as restrictions?

Comment: @Joe: I don't see four *values* but four *conditions* (*equations* if you like). Ponder them again.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What is the difference between restrictions and conditions?

Comment: @Joe: my remark is against *values*.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm not understanding, but does that mean there are four conditions in total?

Comment: @joe: of course not. Your conditions are duplicate.